# convert a varchar column that has timestamp with timezone data to timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, type-conversion

Trying in Oracle SQL Developer

Column A is basically how my data is currently(timestamp with timezone) and I want to convert it to just timestamp

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-06-01T02:00:00-05:00 | 2021-06-01 07:00:00.000 |
| 2021-06-01T00:00:03-06:00 | 2021-06-01 06:00:03.000 |

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-06-01T02:00:00-05:00','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZO') FROM dual
```

Comment: `select CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-06-01T02:00:00-05:00','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS TIMESTAMP) FROM dual`